# Facebook api , Recursive Function and 500 error

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, recursion, facebook-php-sdk

this is my first project using facebook api and facebook PHP sdk , basically i'm trying to get all user statuses. I wrote a script that should work , but i got an 500 error (even if i changed max execution times or set time limit (0)), but only when i use a recursive function inside, take a look to the code :

```
 $request = new FacebookRequest(
 $session,
 'GET',
 '/me/statuses'
 );
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
$x = $graphObject->getProperty('data');
$y = $x->asArray(); //now i got an array
$paging = $graphObject->getProperty('paging'); // i pick paging with "next" and "prevoiuos "
$paged = $paging->asArray();  //as array
$counter = 0 ;              
foreach ($y as $el){
        echo ('<h3>'.$y[$counter]->message.'</h3>');
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "<br/>";
        $counter++;
}

$next = $paged['next']; // now i got url for load 20 more statuses
$response = file_get_contents($next); // get content of url

//recoursive function every time i use looper with content of next
function looper($response){
    $array = json_decode($response, true);  
    $secondarray = ($array['data']);
    $paging = ($array['paging']); // again i pick url for load  next statuses
    $next =  $paging['next'];// again i pick url for load  next statuses
    $nextResponse = file_get_contents($next);// again i pick url for load  next      statuses and i will use this.
    $counter2 = 0 ;             
        foreach ($secondarray as $el){  //  put on page next 20 statuses

                echo ('<h3>'. $secondarray[$counter2]['message'] .'</h3>');
                echo "<br/>";
                echo "<br/>";
                $counter2++;


        }   
        if ( is_null($nextResponse) == false ){ // if in next call i  got 20 more statuses(not empty) call again this function
            looper($nextResponse);
        } else { echo "last message" ; die();}  //else stop.

}

looper($response);
```

}

If i dont recall the function (basically i comment out the if statement) script works fine and prints 20+20 statuses , else it give me 500 internal error.
As i said i tried changin max execution time or set_time_limit(0), but nothing happens.
I'm not sure if problem is my hosting (godaddy) , or if my script is not good / not efficent. any help?
Thanks Nico

Comment: must be infinite recursion you should see what the actual value of $nextResponse is when there is no next response...it might not be null like you want it to be

Comment: do you have any message at php error_log?

Comment: no messages @angeldelrio

Comment: I have never used godaddy but are you sure the do allow changes on php.ini variables? I would check if the script is not reaching memory limit too and as @LoganMurphy said check $nextResponse contents

Comment: in godaddy you can change some php.ini var  in dashboard.
 the fact is that he give me back the error after 10-15 seconds. i dont think in 15 the script can reach the moment when $nextResponse is null (empty) , but i will try to find out if is corret to use is_null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found your issue. You are asigning `$nextResponse` the value returned by `file_get_contents`. See http://php.net/manual/es/function.file-get-contents.php it returns `false` in case of content couldnt be retrieved. Try checking for `false` instead of `null`:

```
        ..........

        if ( false != $nextResponse ){ // if in next call i  got 20 more statuses(not empty) call again this function
            looper($nextResponse);
        } else { echo "last message" ; die();}  //else stop.
```

Comment: By the way i used this in if statement " $nextResponse != false" because  with == he call again the function even if there is no data.